# R, data frame order

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I'm new on R, and I'm trying to figure out this.

I have two data frame(df1 and df2) that I'm just already read from csv.

```
df1:                    df2:

      val                    val
1     a1                1    a2
2     b1                2    b2
3     c1                3    c2
4     d1                4    d2
```

The thing is that I want to create a new data frame with just one column with the information from the two csv interleaved. Something like:

```
      val 
1     a1
2     a2
3     b1
4     b2
5     c1
6     c2
7     d1
8     d2
```

I'd really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option with `Map`

```
data.frame(val = c(mapply(c, df1$val, df2$val)))
#   val
#1  a1
#2  a2
#3  b1
#4  b2
#5  c1
#6  c2
#7  d1
#8  d2
```

---

Or

```
data.frame(val =  c(t(do.call(cbind, list(df1, df2)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

One method to interleave two vectors is to use `rbind` to create a matrix with each vector as a row and then convert the matrix to a vector; This vector will pick up elements from rows alternatively due to how data is stored in a matrix(by column):

```
data.frame(val = as.vector(rbind(df1$val, df2$val)))

#  val
#1  a1
#2  a2
#3  b1
#4  b2
#5  c1
#6  c2
#7  d1
#8  d2
```